# How to load map markers in react native on region change

Tags: react-native

How to load 1000+ markers in slots in react native. I tried with all the markers but it takes lot of time to plot on map. Instead of it , i want to load markers in slots. As a changed region then markers from that particular region should gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`React-native-maps` come with `onRegionChange` prop.
Take the longitude and latitude of the present reason where you want to show the markers and render the marker particularly on that geo location.

As soon as you start scrolling the map, it'll automatically call the `onRegionChange` function and then considering that region change call the function to get the markers on that particular region.

Also slow rendering of maps and high usage of memory and RAM are the bugs of react native maps on using custom markers. [See this open issue in github](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2082).